# JQuery each() function code is running even when there are no elements in the collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in my application. It is supposed to build a comma separated string from a JQuery collection. The collection is retrieved from some xml. I use JQuery each() to iterate. This is standard code that I use all the time. I declare and define the result variable (patientConditions) first and set it to blank. Within the function I add the found string to the result variable along with a comma. I am not bothered by the trailing comma this leaves if there are results. The problem is that with no results the second line within my each() is running - they probably both are. After the loop has completed (with no matching elements in the xml) the value of the result is ','. It should be blank. I think this is something to do with closures, or hoisting, but I am unable to figure out how its happening. I have hacked a solution to this scenario, but am more worried about the hole in my js knowledge :(

```
var patientConditions = '';

$xml.find('patient>prescription>conditions').each(function() {
    var conditionName = $(this).find('condition>name');
    patientConditions += conditionName.text() + ',';
});
```

Comment: please share the xml also

Comment: Hi Arun P Johny, The xml is not relevant. There are no matches in it, so it does not matter. When there are matches this all runs fine. Its the empty case that I am interested in.

Comment: You could put a `console.log(this)` inside the function called by each to see exactly what the find method matched on.

Comment: so there is a match for `patient>prescription>conditions`, but not for  `condition>name`, is it correct

Comment: That's correct. This is the xml: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<patient>
 <prescription>
  <conditions></conditions>
 </prescription>
</patient>

Comment: is this the only operation happening in the loop

Comment: Your problem statement is incorrect.  The element(s) on which you called `.each` _does_ exist, so the callback is invoked.  It's the code _inside_ the callback that is failing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand  there is a match for `patient>prescription>conditions`, but not for `condition>name`, in that case `$(this).find('condition>name')` will return a zero elemet set. then `.text()` on that set will return a empty string

```
$xml.find('patient>prescription>conditions').each(function() {
    var conditionName = $(this).find('condition>name');
    if(conditionName.length){
        patientConditions += conditionName.text() + ',';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a jQuery object is used to find non existant nodes, in this case `$(this).find('condition>name')`. The jQuery object still exists, it just contains no association to a node. This will allow you to run all jQuery functions on this object despite it not having any reference. This is why `conditionName.text()` returns an empty string despite no node being present. The solution, check if the node exists before doing anything.

```
var patientConditions = '';

$xml.find('patient>prescription>conditions').each(function() {
    var conditionName = $(this).find('condition>name');

    if (conditionName.length > 0) {
        patientConditions += conditionName.text() + ',';
    } else {
        // Do something if node doesnt exist
    }
});
```